# Rapid CSS Testing with JSP

Tags: css, jsp, weblogic

I am new to web development and am unfamiliar with some of the methods for best testing the web end information. On my current project I am using Weblogic to deploy my JSP project through Eclipse.

The webpages build fine and everything works, but currently I am restarting my localhost server every time I make a change to the css or the jsp, which a single round trip can be up to 3-5 min. is there a more efficient way of testing the css other than restarting my server every time? What about jsp?

Edit: Followup:
For any that stumble past this: After reading up on different staging methods as @better_use_mkstemp suggested, I couldn't figure out how to explicitly set eclipse up to stage or nostage deploy, however I did find some nifty things.

You can do an Incremental push (expand drop down in the servers view in eclipse, right click project that is deployed on a running server > click "Incremental Publish". This only pushes what has changed since last push) which helps a bit.

The other thing I found was an automatic deploy when a file changes, but that had it pushing while I was still editing the file which was a bit annoying. Using this feature you can also have it auto deploy each time there is a new version, but I didn't play around with that since we're not changing the version number yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how you are deploying your application. If you deploy using `nostage` mode, the server(s) will keep looking in the original deployment directory and will automatically detect jsp changes for refreshes.

This is as opposed to `stage` mode, where the original war/ear deployment is actually copied to each individual server.

Read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/deploy.html#wp1027044

Sounds like if you keeps dropping your updated deployment files in the same directory with nostage you won't need a restart.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find a way to get it quite work, but you're advice lead me to something that helped a little bit. (see question)